# Performance measuring with prof

Tags: c++, c, profiling, gprof

Is there a way to run linux's `prof` in a way equivalent to what a program with `-gprof` would do? I know wouldn't be exact, but only statistically correct.

I'm basically looking for a way to do a `gprof`-like analysis on a C/C++ program that includes debug symbols, but without recompiling it.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: Which tool? I'm not aware of any stack analysing one apart from callgrind... but that's not it really.

Comment: Use callgrind (or cachegrind) and then use kcachegrind for visualization (on the output file from valgrind). It has per-function analysis. I'm very happy with the data it provides.  http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html

Comment: [Statistically correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028198/inaccuracy-in-gprof-output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm very satisfied lately by CPU profiler of the [Google performance tools](http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/). Programs basically run at undistorted normal speed under it. No recompilation is required, linking against a special libraries is recommended but using LD_PRELOAD is also possible in most cases.